# If I use a stream for base class constructor, can I use the rest of the stream for derived?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stringstream

Let's say I have two classes; class A and class B, where class B inherits from class A.

I am reading data from a file. When I construct A, I get 4 parameters from that file, and when constructing B I get an extra one:

```
A(istream& is){
    std::string line;
        std::getline(is, line); //get a line from the file

        std::stringstream ss(line);

    //Initialize the member variables in class A.
}
B(istream& is) : A(is) {

// Constructs A, and then initialize the extra member
// variable of B.

}
```

My problem is that after class A is instantiated when constructing B, the fifth parameter read from the file, in the 'ss' stream is lost.

How could I solve this?

PD: Is a school exercise so I am not allowed to change any definitions.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: You can not use the original `is` to initialize `A` for the solution, given that interface. Either that, or `A` must not consume a full line but only individual parameters.

Comment: First of all I would recommend you separate construction from file-reading. When you do that, it's easier to handle as then you could use virtual functions to parse the contents of the line in the string stream. It could be passed to a function `parse`, and `B::parse` first does `A::parse(ss)` and then uses `ss` to extract its own data.